# How to read POST data in the Guile web server

Tags: guile

In Guile's web server I can't seem to find any documentation on reading POST data. It seems to be sent to my entrypoint function as "body" along with the "request". It looks like body is encoded as a bytevector and I can decode it into a string:

```
(use-modules (rnrs bytevectors))
(utf8->string body)
```

So from here I could proceed to parse the string, but that seems rather tedious and error prone. Is there no way to read the POST data as a list of some kind?

Comment: Indeed POST data is the body but it's encoded using some RFC which is not supported yet in Guile.

Comment: What you can do to work around that, is send a json based on your form instead of doing a raw HTTP POST...

Comment: Thanks for the replies, in light of that info I was searching around for alternatives and found "Artanis" which is a GNU webserver framework for Guile and it looks like it supports POST and also better handling of static files, which sounds much closer to my needs. So I think I'll just be looking into that.

Comment: I don't find how to support POST forms in artanis? Can you post a response to your question so that I can upvote it? tx!

Comment: Sorry to say I actually wasn't able to get it working in artanis in the end either. But the way it's supposed to work has a few examples in here: https://www.gnu.org/software/artanis/manual/manual.html
I still look forward to being able to do this with guile in the future, but I guess it just needs a bit more development first (or maybe it's already working in artanis but I just wasn't doing it right)

Comment: Actually I know how to do that. Sorry I forgot about it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of `decode` procedure which will convert a `BODY` into an association list of lists where the key is the name of the form field and the value is a list of values associated with that key. Mind the fact that the "value" associated with a given key in the assoc returned by `decode` is always a list.

```
(define-module (web decode))

(use-modules (ice-9 match))
(use-modules (rnrs bytevectors))
(use-modules (srfi srfi-1))
(use-modules (srfi srfi-26))
(use-modules (web uri))

;;;
;;; decode
;;;

(define (acons-list k v alist)
  "Add V to K to alist as list"
  (let ((value (assoc-ref alist k)))
    (if value
        (let ((alist (alist-delete k alist)))
          (acons k (cons v value) alist))
        (acons k (list v) alist))))

(define (list->alist lst)
  "Build a alist of list based on a list of key and values.

   Multiple values can be associated with the same key"
  (let next ((lst lst)
             (out '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        out
        (next (cdr lst) (acons-list (caar lst) (cdar lst) out)))))

(define-public (decode bv)
  "Convert BV querystring or form data to an alist"
  (define string (utf8->string bv))
  (define pairs (map (cut string-split <> #\=)
                     ;; semi-colon and amp can be used as pair separator
                     (append-map (cut string-split <> #\;)
                                 (string-split string #\&))))
  (list->alist (map (match-lambda
                      ((key value)
                       (cons (uri-decode key) (uri-decode value)))) pairs)))
```

Comment: I have a project on github where I try to gather all the missing pieces from guile stdlib https://github.com/a-guile-mind/guile-web